# Unable to find pip package

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-model-analysis

I have been using bazel build for my im2txt model from TensorFlow and it shows me

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`

I have installed the package nltk and tried to even create an environment and run the bazel script

Is there anyway i need to link my python to bazel for the python modules to be installed separately on an environment ?

Repo i am trying to run : [im2txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/im2txt)

Code sample which iam running :

```
# Location to save the MSCOCO data.
MSCOCO_DIR="${HOME}/im2txt/data/mscoco"

# Build the preprocessing script.
cd research/im2txt
bazel build //im2txt:download_and_preprocess_mscoco

# Run the preprocessing script.
bazel-bin/im2txt/download_and_preprocess_mscoco "${MSCOCO_DIR}"   ##Error here <----
```

Comment: remove this import, run somewhere in script:
`from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions
p = get_installed_distributions()
print(p)`

Comment: I dont understand what you mentioned earlier can you please elaborate @Misieq

Comment: First of all, check older versions of nltk, offten packages right after update aren't compatible with other packages

Comment: I think it has something to do with bazel and not the pip packages itself

Comment: Even if i try to run `from pip._internal...` it throws me `no module named 'pip' installed`

Comment: You can try using Anaconda, as some basic packages like `pip` are installed already.